# Wordpress Admin Dashboard not working. It does not load css files. Also the website is not able to edit using the customize buttons etc

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I am not able to edit the Wordpress site at all. [The dashboard looks like its not loading css.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbBak.png) [But also the links are not working, each time I press anything on the bare-looking dashboard, it takes me to Page not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVA5O.png) I am facing this issue because I changed the admin password from phpMyadmin using cPanel. From that moment, this is all messed up. It would be awesome if I get a solution for this. (Ps. I do have a backup of the site but it is old, so it does not have a lot of changes done recently, so I cannot roll back to old version

Comment: Have you used md5 when changing the password?
If yes, then clear your cookies and cache and log in again using the new password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any cache plugin, then deactivate it, clear your browser cookies, also try to access it from different IP from another place.

Also, check this [link](https://njengah.com/wordpress-admin-css-not-loading/#:%7E:text=Clear%20cookies%20and%20cache%20to,delete%20recently%20added%20WordPress%20plugins) for a better understanding.